# How to redirect guest to login page instead of homepage phpbb3

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I would like to keep the entire forum private. Hence I removed the permissions of guest to the forums and all other features as suggested by other people. However when the user visits the forums, he is shown the home page but not the login page.

Can anyone suggest me the right way to do this without hacking the index.php or other core elements of phpbb3?

Comment: https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1978095 No code needed!

Answer (score 3):

Know I'm coming in late but I hard-coded a redirect:

```
if ($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS)
{
    header('Location: [your phpbb location]/ucp.php?mode=login');
    exit;
}
```

right **after** these lines

```
// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup('viewforum');
```

in the index.php file found in the root of your phpbb project.

This will redirect unauthorized users directly to the login page as soon as they hit the index.php page.

NOTE: **Anytime** an unauthorized user hits the index file they will be redirected to the login page (e.g. after logging out)

Comment: Excellent! after a long search I got this answer. Thanks

Comment: Worked! I used it on the viewtopic_body page so that only logged in users can see posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($user->data['username']=='Anonymous'){
//logic of login tpl
}
else {
//normal homepage tpl
}
```

I have that the above code works for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Set your permissions to give your guests no access. They will be required to login to do anything because only registered users will have access (particularly view access).